# How to set the column of Child gridview in Parent gridview column to be hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having the Nested Gridview in my Web form. Based on the Parent childgridview column value, child gridview column to be hyperlink otherwise the child gridview column should be normal text column.

Comment: First, show your work. Second, did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution for my problem

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="38%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
<ItemTemplate>
<div align="center">
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkDepartmentName" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:HyperLink>
<asp:Label ID="lblDepartmentName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DepartmentName") >'></asp:Label>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**I placed the Hyperlink and Label field inside the Template Field in the Child Gridview. Based on the Parent Grid value, i turned On and OFF the Visibility of the hyperlink and label field inside the Gridview in the Child Gridview RowDatabound event. Tats it my problem solved.**